# How to ignore a record in the last line of the CSV file using Apache Commons CSV java?

Tags: java, csv, java-8, apache-commons-csv

I'm using Apache Commons CSV to read a CSV file. The file have an information about the file itself (date and time of generation) at the last line.

```
|XXXX                                |XXXXX|XXXXX|XXXX|
|XXXX                                |XXXXX|XXXXX|XXXX|
|File generation: 21/01/2019 17.34.00|     |     |    |
```

So while parsing the file, I'm getting this as a record(obviously).
I'm wondering is there any way to get rid of it from parsing and does Apache Commons CSV have any provision to handle it.

Comment: Can you share the code what you have written?

Comment: you can check records.size() from CSVParser and loop through size()-1

Answer (score 1):

It's a while loop and you wouldn't know when you get to the end until you get to the end. You have two options:

- Bad option: Read it once and count the number of lines and then
  when you read it the second time you can `break` the loop when you
  reach (counter-1) line.
- Good option: It seems like your files are pipe delimited so when
  you're processing line by line simply make sure that
  `line.trim().spit("|").length() > 1` or in your case do some work as
  long as the number of records per line is greater than 1. This will
  ensure you don't apply your logic on the lines with just one column
  which happens to be your last row aka footer.

Example taken from Apache commons and modified a litte

```
Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/file.csv");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    //all lines except the last will result greater than 1
    if (record.size() > 1){ 
        //do your work here 
        String columnOne = record.get(0);
        String columnTwo = record.get(1);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Apache Commons CSV provides a function to ignore the header (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withSkipHeaderRecord--), but don't offer a solution to ignore the `footer`. But you can simply get all records, except the last one by manually ignoring the last record.